# IDAT PNG chunk, first byte unexpected, where am I wrong?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, png, deflate, inflate

I created a png 3x3 with 3 different colours and 1 2x2 black and white for testing purpose.

Basically I've been able to allocate all the bits of the bytes to their specific role in their respective Chunk but the IDAT one (not unexpected).

the first byte after the IDAT type declaration is the following in binary 8 format:

```
00011000
```

where basically, following the online documentation:

0001 should be the CM =1
1000 should be the CINFO =8

But I expected to find a 1000 (=8) as CM (standard compression method for pngs).

Where am I wrong? Here the complete datastream.

After understood this part I'm going to implement the INFLATE/DEFLATE algorithm in a software on which it still is not build.

Here the complete datastream for the IDAT Chunk
DataStream:

```
000110000101011101100011111110000000111100000100000011000000110000100000111010101111111101111111
0000000000111000110101000000100011111000
```

Comment: CM is the bottom nibble, CINFO is the top nibble.

Comment: thanks @harold. on the documentation I can see:
            bits 0 to 3  CM     Compression method
            bits 4 to 7  CINFO  Compression info
Why should I read 0 to 3 as the last bit, that I usually would read as 4-7?

Also, should I revert all the 0-3 and 4-7 in all the subsequet bytes, while creating the datastream?

Comment: Because bits are usually numbered from the bottom, I'm not sure if there's really a good reason for it (though it does make it obvious what their weight is, eg bit 3 has weight 2³) but that's how it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered in a comment, but as stated in the [document you are reading](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) (it helps to read the whole thing):

```
  In the diagrams below, we number the
  bits of a byte so that bit 0 is the least-significant bit, i.e.,
  the bits are numbered:

     +--------+
     |76543210|
     +--------+
```

You do not need to "implement the INFLATE/DEFLATE algorithm in a software", since that has already been done for you with [zlib](http://zlib.net/).

Comment: Dear Dt Adler, I read a lot of your comments, thanks for what you are doing. I need to implement the inflate/deflate algorithm since I'm trying to post-process the png with a software unable to do it. Do you have any recommendation on how to proceed?